# Plotted map from shape file seems distorted

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm trying to plot a map of Germany but the plot seems distorted to me.

[image: Distorted map of Germany]

I would like to get an outcome that looks more like this:

[image: Reference map of Germany]

The first plot I generated from a shape file the following way using GeoPandas:

```
map_ = gpd.read_file(r'PATH\VG250_Kreisgrenzen_2018.shp')
map_.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4839'}
map_.plot()
```

I tried using different epsg codes, but I didn't really see a difference in the actual outcome. Is there any other way to get an outcome, less distorted, maybe by editing the scale of the Y-Axis?

Comment: You could try something like the following. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` `ax.set_xlim(0,14)` `ax.set_ylim(0,55)` `map_.plot(ax=ax,scalex=False,scaley=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using:

```
map_ = map_.to_crs({'init' :'epsg:25832'})
```

the command `.to_csr` wasn't working before. I had to update pyproj to Version 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 different projects I have to place on the same `ax` with a specified `figsize=(16, 9)`.  After wrestling with distortion issues that appeared to depend on how narrow the projection was, I added `plt.axis('equal')` and it fixed the issue.  Specifically, I had a smaller GeoJSON that I wanted to be "zoomed in" on relative to state borders, the the order of the code was as follows:

```
df.plot(figsize=(16, 9), aspect=None)  # smaller geojson
plt.axis('equal')  # necessary to be placed here to prevent projection distortion
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = ax.axis()  # "zoom in" on geojson
ax.axis((xmin - 0.5, xmax + 0.5, ymin - 0.5, ymax + 0.5))
states = gpd.read_file(self.states_path)
states.plot(ax=ax, aspect=None, facecolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), edgecolor=(0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.8))  # plot the state borders
```